# get actual height of svg bezier curved path

Tags: svg, bezier

This is more of a bezier question than an SVG question, but here goes...

given the following code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" baseProfile="full" viewBox="0 0 400 400" baseProfile="full">
    <path d="M0,0 C20,400 30,200 50,100" fill="#FF0000" stroke="#000000"/>
</svg>
```

Using `[path].getBBox()` returns me a height of 400, since the 1st control point of the curve is at 400 `y`, and this makes sense(ish).

But what I really need is the actual height of the object as rendered, not the box that contains all points used in its drawing.

I'm assuming I'm just going to have to figure it out myself? And if that's the case, does anybody have any suggestions for where to go to find such mathy things? I did some googling, but I'm not really coming up with anything (it's very possible I'm not phrasing the question correctly, some help in that regard would be super nice as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it right, it's a [WebKit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=53512). If you [try `getBBox`](http://jsfiddle.net/8x5BK/) on Firefox or even Internet Explorer, it's fine.

If you need a workaround, give a look at the [implementation done for SVG-edit](https://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/source/browse/trunk/editor/svgutils.js#328).

Comment: Thanks, that blows. Looks like they've been working on that fix for 2 years with no resolution. And at least the fix has comments which include a link to a nice mathy answer.